# How to find double values in a array and combine the double values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a way to filter out double values, as my example below shows that the are products present in the array that are basically double and should be combined(make a new key with the values combined).

The product should be combined by api_id.

```
//old current array
[products] => Array
    (
        [product_5c7fb5f72f9d5_192] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 84721
                [api_id] => 192
                [amount] => 12
                [cost_price] => 3.36
            )
        [product_5c7fb5f72fe49_192] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 84722
                [api_id] => 177
                [amount] => 1
                [cost_price] => 1.09
            )
        [product_5c7fb5f7301b2_192] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 84724
                [api_id] => 192
                [amount] => 24
                [cost_price] => 6.72
            )
        [product_5c7fb5f7301b2_192] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 84725
                [api_id] => 192
                [amount] => 24
                [cost_price] => 6.72
            )
    )

// this should be new new array
[products] => Array
    (
        [product_5c7fb5f72f9d5_192] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 84721
                [api_id] => 192
                [amount] => 60//new value
                [cost_price] => 16.8//new value
            )
        [product_5c7fb5f72fe49_192] => Array
            (
                [record_id] => 84722
                [api_id] => 177
                [amount] => 1
                [cost_price] => 1.09
            )

    )
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`:

```
$products = array_reduce($products, function ($carry, $product) {
    if (!isset($carry[$product['api_id']])) {
        $carry[$product['api_id']] = $product;
    }
    else {
        $carry[$product['api_id']]['amount'] += $product['amount'];
        $carry[$product['api_id']]['cost_price'] += $product['cost_price'];
    }

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Comment: nice solution, never heard about `array_reduce` before